# pip could not install asyncmongo

Tags: python, pip

I'm very new in Python and need to install asyncmongo package for my environment. But when I
excuting `pip install asyncmongo` it fails with the following error.

```
C:\git\project>pip install asyncmongo
Downloading/unpacking asyncmongo
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement asyncmongo
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external asyncmongo to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for asyncmongo
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Name\pip\pip.log
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue just now (guessing that the library you're trying to install doesn't have a distribution up on the repository which pip is using).  Instead, install the `easy_install` utility and do:

```
easy_install asyncmongo
```

Also, as a side note, I'd recommend using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper which comes with pip/easy_install.

They segregate your python installs and it is basically like using a python install for every project you work on instead of sharing it globally.  It includes both pip and easy_install which is useful because when I can't find something with `pip` or if the `pip` install fails, I'm usually able to find it with `easy_install`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem was caused because of asyncmongo 1.2.2 sources was hasted on the amazon file server, so in that case pip should be invoked with additional flags (`--allow-external packagename` and `--allow-unverified packagename`)  so to install it properly follwing command should be executed:

```
pip install --allow-external asyncmongo --allow-unverified asyncmongo asyncmongo
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on Windows platform and pip is not as great for Windows as for Linux or Mac. `easy_install` has some some advantages on Windows, such as installing a precompiled `.exe` binary.

On a different note, you may consider using [motor](http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) instead of `asyncmongo`. It is newer and looks more elegant.